# Can I get crampons for small feet?

Tags: mountaineering, crampons

All manufacturers that I can find offering adjustable crampons with smallest size 35 EU. I need crampons for a boots 30-32 EU size. Is it possible to find such crampons?

I am looking for glacier trekking crampons.

Comment: Cutting down the centre bar would not help much. It's also necessary to adjust crampons width

Comment: You're essentially looking at kid-sized crampons. There's not much of a market for kids ice-climbing gear, because kids and sharp pointy things don't pair very well...

Comment: Are you looking for vertical ice climbing crampons? Or glacier trekking crampons?

Comment: @ShemSeger I'm looking for a glacier trekking crampons

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have a pair of **Charlet Moser** walking crampons, and just for fun, I fit them onto my 3 year old's size 25 winter boots (US/CAN size 9C):

[image]

I had to cheat of course, I removed the bar that attaches the toe and heel peices, then overlapped them. But looking at the crampons, I think they fit a size 32 natively (US/CAN size 1).

There isn't really a market for children's-sized technical crampons. I think the best thing you're going to find on the market is probably a pair of slip-on shoe spikes such as what I have pictured below:

[image]

[These crampons](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01M6426HA) are made for kids shoes, and fit a size 28-39 (US/CAN 11C - 6.5), and to be honest are probably adequate for anything a kid that size is going to have the ability for.